# NewFormUrl stops user field from saving data

Tags: document-set, user, spfield

I have a custom content type inheriting from document set.  The content type has various # of fields, including two user (e.g. Person or Group) fields.

```
<Field ID="{2B2CA4F1-4F2C-40E9-A4B2-5ACAEFD8BAFA}" Name="DocSetFieldF" DisplayName="DocSet Field F" Type="User" Required="False" Group=".Temp Columns" List="UserInfo" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"></Field>
<Field ID="{5CBAFDB8-58F1-4453-A1E0-F01DF8D696D0}" Name="DocSetFieldG" DisplayName="DocSet Field G" Type="User" Required="False" Group=".Temp Columns" List="UserInfo" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"></Field>
```

Now when I create a new item of this content type, it runs fine and all my data is saved correctly.

But if I attempt to change the NewFormUrl of the content type within my list instance to a custom version of the newdocset.aspx in the layouts folder, my page now shows duplicate labels and my input for the user fields stops saving.  And any attempt to reset the NewFormUrl either makes more duplicate labels or doesn't change anything.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so... turns out this is just something that SharePoint 2013 can't handle.

I had to resort to filling out a list with my users and attaching a lookup field to the list.  It's not as UI friendly, but at least it works... for now.